# Como alterar um valor de um objeto literal JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos

Estou tentando alterar o valor de uma propriedade em um objeto JavaScript, porém na criação do objeto de modo literal, e não construtor.

```js
var cliente = {
  nome: "Wesley",
  idade: 20,
  cargo: "Front End",
  setAtualiza : functiion(n, i, c){
    this.nome = n;
    this.idade = i;
    this.cargo = c
  }
};

setAtualiza("NovoNome", 25, "Pleno");
for(var x in cliente){
  console.log(cliente[x]);
};

setAtualiza();
```

E a saída que eu gostaria de ter é: "NovoNome 25 Pleno"

O que estou fazendo de errado? Ou isso não é possível fazer (atualizar um objeto literal).

Comment: Cadê a função setAtualiza?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Além de um erro de digitação você está chamando uma função que não existe globalmente, ela só existe no contexto do objeto cliente, então você deve chamá-la através do objeto.

```js
var cliente = {
    nome: "Wesley",
    idade: 20,
    cargo: "Front End",
    setAtualiza : function(n, i, c) { //tinha um erro de digitação aqui.
        this.nome = n;
        this.idade = i;
        this.cargo = c
    }
};

cliente.setAtualiza("NovoNome", 25, "Pleno"); //a chamada deve ser contextual
for (var x in cliente) {
    console.log(cliente[x]); //mudei aqui só executar certo no SO, pode manter o seu
};
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Object/ChangeLiteral.js).

Comment: De fato, funcionou sim! O problema é que ele também está mostrando toda a função 'setAtualiza'. Ou seja, o ideal é apresentar apenas os três primeiros valores, deixando de lado a função.
Imagina se tenho mais uma função ali, ele iria retornar ela também, correto? Por favor... Quase lá!

Comment: Isto já é outra pergunta. Listar os membros de um objeto serve para poucas coisas práticas. Ou você tem que filtrar na mão o que você quer ou usar alguns artifícios não padronizados para esse filtro ocorrer automaticamente. Nenhum é ideal. Não vou detalhar porque este é outro assunto.

Comment: Entendo.

Nas suas praticas, então, qual a melhor definição para atualizar os valores de um objeto: uma função local ou uma função global? Fiz com uma função global aqui e funcionou corretamente.

Comment: Para este tipo de utilização eu acho que é melhor a função local ao objeto, mas não sei se isto é idiomático em JS, eu daria esta preferência na maioria dos casos. O problema aí é tentar listar todos os membros, raramente isto é desejável a não ser em testes e verificações, o que eu achei que era por isto que tinha feito este código. Listar os membros eu acredito não ser idiomático nenhum nenhuma linguagem já que cada contexto você pode querer fazer de um jeito, então você não pode se valor da estrutura do objeto.

Answer (score 5):

Function está escrito incorretamente e para realizar a chamada de um método você precisa de uma referência ao objeto em questão. Neste caso essa referência pode ser acessada através da variável cliente. Segue bloco de código alterado:

```js
var cliente = {
  nome: "Wesley",
  idade: 20,
  cargo: "Front End",
  setAtualiza : function(n, i, c){
    this.nome = n;
    this.idade = i;
    this.cargo = c
  }
};

cliente.setAtualiza("NovoNome", 25, "Pleno");
for(var x in cliente){
  console.log(cliente[x]);
};
```

Comment: O mesmo acontece com Bigown, está mostrando o conteúdo dentro da função 'setAtualiza'. O ideal é que ele pare antes de entrar nestas funções, e retornar apenas os valores que de fato fazem sentido. Obrigado!

Comment: Você pode criar uma função "toString()" dentro do próprio objeto e nessa função você listar apenas o que te interessa. Ex: toString : function(){ return "nome: " + this.nome + " idade: "+this.idade + " cargo: "+ this.cargo }. E na hora de exibir, vcê invocaria console.log(cliente.toString()).

Answer (score 4):

Faltou chamar a função **no próprio objeto, como método**. Da maneira como você fez, deve estar dando um erro porque a função não existe fora do objeto. Em código, quero dizer isto:

```
cliente.setAtualiza("NovoNome", 25, "Pleno");
//  ˆ---- faltou isto!
```

Comment: Tam também o [erro de digitação que o bigown citou](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58183/74), eu não havia reparado.